# cv::findContours OPenCV 2.4

Tags: opencv, kinect, contour

I am working with OpenCV 2.4, I want to detect contours of Hand and draw them using Kinect.
I am using cv::findContours(imageContour,contours,CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0)); 
and its working fine but when I try to add the hierarchy it caused some problems.
cv::findContours(imageContour,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE,Point(0,0));

Also After using the first choice when I try to accesses these contours in: 
double area0 = contourArea(contours,false);
Or
cv::drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 1, 8);

I get Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
And I don't know how to draw them or get the Area, Any clue ?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: can you post some code? anyway, this could help: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html

Comment: I solved this issue by moving to Cvseq* and implemented the whole code in this style and it worked thank you  @nkint

Comment: But there is another tricky problem when converting the code, the CvSeq* hull= cvConvexHull2(biggestContour, storage2 , 1, 0); 
CvSeq* defects=cvConvexityDefects(biggestContour, hull, storage3);      give back CvSeq*,@nkint

Comment: and when I want to use a method for example its header is vector<int> filterHulls(vector<int>, vector<Point>, RotatedRect); I have to convert all to CvSeq*, Morover when I want to convert the pints[index].x were points is the contour and index is the hull for example, I did CvPoint* p = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM( CvPoint, inputIndex, i );CvPoint* p1 = CV_GET_SEQ_ELEM( CvPoint, inputPoints, p->y ); @nkint

Comment: And then refering to this by ' p1->y ' instead of (inputPoints[inputIndex[i]].y) ..but ofcourse it is not working ...do you have any clue ? @nkint

Comment: i have not a lot of experience with c api (i'm using the new opencv2 c++ api) and it's not very clear what you wanto to do. please post some complete example and a test image, we'll going to resole it